# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenv.seed.embed.via_app_data' when I created new env by virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I was creating a new virtual environment on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
$ virtualenv my_env
```

But it gave an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenv.seed.embed.via_app_data'
```

---

Other info:

```
$ virtualenv --version
virtualenv 20.0.17 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv/__init__.py
```

Comment: for those of you using poetry & on Ubuntu 20.04 or its variant [this](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2972) thread on github helped me solve my problem.

Comment: Thanks @Umar.H, that worked for me with poetry on (Ubuntu-based) Mint 20.2 (tl;dr: `sudo apt remove --purge python3-virtualenv`)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Try to create the virtual environment using directly venv module

```
python3 -m venv my_env
```

Comment: Can't this problem be fixed?

Comment: I think `virtualenv` is using a different python installation that your `python3` default installation, thus the ModuleNotFoundError. Easiest way to get around this is to use directly venv python 3 module. I don't know from the top of my head how to make virtualenv tool use the same python environment as `python3` link is using.

Comment: To activate `source my_env/bin/activate`

Answer (score 136):

@yushulx
I also ran into the same issue. I installed both via `pip3` and via `sudo apt install python3-virtualenv` and it gave me an error but after I ran `pip3 uninstall virtualenv` I could create a virtualenv without issue

Comment: I did vice-versa `sudo apt remove python3-virtualenv` and that worked as well. Clearly a result of mixing those up.

Answer (score 53):

To fix this on Ubuntu 20.04, I had to uninstall `virtualenv` from the system: `apt remove python3-virtualenv`, and reinstall it using `pip`: `pip install --user virtualenv --force-reinstall`. I had errors about dependencies conflicts, I fixed them by calling `pip install --user ${package} --force-reinstall` for every package involved.

Comment: this worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: Same on Ubuntu 20.04, but I only needed the first part (uninstall python3-virtualenv). Not sure if it's relevant, but the system had both python3-venv and python3-virtualenv installed (via apt). I do not understand why this worked, but it did.

Comment: `sudo apt remove python3-virtualenv` works for me.

Comment: This works on 2022 while I am still using Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 32):

`virtualenv` is installed by default with python itself and when you install `virtualenv` via `pip3` and try to create virtual environment using `pipenv` you will get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenv.seed.embed.via_app_data
```

Check the version of installed `virtualenv` using `apt list --installed`:

`python3-virtualenv/focal,focal,now 20.0.17-1 all [installed,automatic]`
with  the installed `virtualenv` by `pip3`:

```
virtualenv             20.4.0
```

Default installation of `virtualenv` is different with `pip3` installed `virtualenv`

So when you try to create a virtual environment using `pipenv` (for example installing Django in a directory `home/user/django` with `pipenv install django~=3.1.5` you will get that error.

The ***solution*** is to remove installed `virtualenv` using `pip3 uninstall virtualenv` and use the default installation of `virtualenv`. This time when you create virtual environment with `pipenv` it will create it successfully.

Answer (score 18):

I want to have `virtualenvwrapper`. On `Debian 10 testing` I did:

```
apt remove python3-virtualenvwrapper  # not purge, I want no changes in ~/.virtualenvs/
apt purge python3-virtualenv
/usr/bin/python3.8 -m pip install --force-reinstall virtualenvwrapper
/usr/bin/python3.8 -m pip install --force-reinstall virtualenv==20.0.23
```

`.24` no longer works. I hope it will be solved sometimes...

**EDIT 2021.01**: I have changed my stack to: `pyenv + pyenv-virtualenvwrapper + poetry`. Ie. I use no apt or pip installation of virtualenv or virtualenvwrapper, and instead I install `pyenv`'s plugin `pyenv-virtualenvwrapper`. This is easier way.

Comment: note: Seems if you have the "apt..." installation, removing/purging is not required. Just apply the last command with ...==20.0.23 and it should be enough.

Comment: + I had more troubles later (I am not sure what I made before), mkvirtualenv was no longer found, previous gave the error "No module found.." again. I was then successfull with user (ie. not root) installation only. :(

Comment: .... so I had often some troubles with apt or pip installation of virtualenv+virtualenvwrapper. At this time the combination of pyenv + its virtualenvwrapper plugin (without apt or pip install) looks good for me. For details read my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65465391/2520298

Answer (score 8):

If someone encounters this problem inside existing env (when for example using pyenv) you can also use command below (found on [GitHub](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2972#issuecomment-765029186) when tried to fix poetry virtual env installation):

```sh
pip install --force-reinstall virtualenv
```

Answer (score 5):

I also had same issue, seems installed version has different user level so I followed their doc and below one work for me:

```
python3 -m virtualenv --help
```

To create new environment:

```
python3 -m virtualenv my_env
```

Answer (score 4):

When I installed `virtualenv` via `pip3`, it failed to run `virtualenv` command. Then I changed the installation via:

```
sudo apt install python3-virtualenv
```

The `virtualenv` command can normally work.

Comment: This worked for me. Actually a lot of mess is around due to python2 & 3 and this was on the top of it.

Answer (score 4):

I too had this issue.  What I found is it is a permissions issue.  For some unknown reason ownership of my home directory was off.  I did a `chown -R` for the directory I was using for my project making myself the owner of my own directory and now everything works as normal.

Comment: Brilliant, I had to just add sudo to my command.

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same issue but after removing **virtualenv** which was installed with **pip3**, I could get rid of this error. Uninstall virtualenv with below command (don't forget to use sudo)

```
sudo pip3 uninstall virtualenv
```

After this, virtualenv command works totally fine.

Answer (score 2):

Install venv package using this command

```
sudo apt install python3.8-venv
```

Create virtual environment using this command

```
python3 -m venv env
```

Activate virtual environment using this command

```
source env/bin/activate
```

Decative virtual environment using this command

```
deactivate
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that there are two virtualenv in your system.
One is "pip install" by sudo or root, the other may be installed by apt(if you are using ubuntu os)
Just uninstall one of them and the error should be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this error by removing all virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper related packages on system and reinstall the virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper with pip with below command(as i use ubuntu, so below only show apt)
remove all packages shown in below result

```
apt list --installed | grep virtualenvwrapper 
apt list --installed | grep virtualenvwrapper
```

install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper with pip

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper virtualenvwrapper
```

set ~/.zshrc

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/amd
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_SCRIPT=/home/robot/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=$(which python3)
source /home/robot/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

When we use pip3 or python3 to install `virtualenv` then I got that error too. I had to run each time to create virtualenv (my_env is virtual environment name)

```
python3 -m virtualenv my_env
```

But if I install it using

```
sudo apt install virtualenv
```

Then `virtualenv` command works fine.

```
virtualenv my_env
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have tried to install using pip command earlier uninstall

```
pip uninstall virtualenv
```

then try to create virtual env

```
virtualenv my_name
```