# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenv.seed.via_app_data

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, pipenv, pipfile

I had installed **virtualenv** by `sudo -H pip3 install virtualenv`, and created a venv by virtualenv, but now I can't create env in my new **Django** project that includes **Pipfile**.
I tried:

`$ pipenv shell`

But its result is:

```
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: /home/mostafa/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/carfix/Pipfile
Using /usr/bin/python3.8 (3.8.5) to create virtualenv...
⠹ Creating virtual environment...ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenv.seed.via_app_data'

✘ Failed creating virtual environment
```

I tried these answers but the problem is not yet resolved:

1. [Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63491221/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-virtualenv-seed-embed-via-app-data-when-i)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally found the solution to the problem:

I Used poetry lockfor one app and everything worked fine!

I Used poetry lock for a second app and received the following error message:

```
$ poetry lock 

Creating virtualenv mytestapp-vm7OCEgV-py3.8 in /home/alexb7217/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs

  ModuleNotFoundError

  No module named 'virtualenv.seed.via_app_data'

  at <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:973 in _find_and_load_unlocked
```

Followed the most simple suggestion:

```
$ sudo apt remove --purge python3-virtualenv
```

Re-ran poetry-lock

```
$ poetry lock  
Updating dependenciesResolving dependencies... (1.1s)
```

Everything works great, that's it! ;)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to remove the installed virtualenv using

> pip3 uninstall virtualenv

And use the default installation of virtualenv then :

> pipenv shell

Comment: thanks Gaëtan GR, I tried its but problem is not resolved :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove your virtualenv installation and try to install it via:

`sudo apt-get install virtualenv`.

Then create virtualenv with:

`virtualenv virtualenv_dir`

Where virtualenv_dir is your Django project folder

Comment: I tried this, its not working @Matteo Pasini

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was not able to select an existing environment nor create one.
What I did was to create one from the terminal:

```
virtualenv venv
```

get into it

```
. venv/bin/activate
```

install the requirements I had, with pip3 no pip:

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

and when I went back to pycharm, it asked me if I wanted to use that environment I just created.

Comment: Prior to that, I had reistalled pycharm.