# testing using tox and pyenv on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, pytest, pyenv, tox

I am trying to run test suite on [requests](https://github.com/psf/requests) code base on Ubuntu 20.04. I noticed that it needs tox and different python versions to run different tests and compatibility checks.
I did the following:

1. Installed tox using:

```
$> pip install tox
```

2. Installed pyenv as per documentation [here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation)
3. Installed python 3.7 using pyenv. I was able to create and use virtual environment using pyenv after this step.

```
# install python 3.7.17
$ requests> pyenv install 3.7
# make it available to the project
$ requests> pyenv local 3.7.17
```

4. Execute tox only for python 3.7

```
$ requests> tox -e py37
```

On doing so i get the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenv.seed.embed.via_app_data'
```

It doesn't seem to work, even-though I have virtualenv and virtualenv-wrapper installed already. How do I get it to work?

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63491221/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-virtualenv-seed-embed-via-app-data-when-i

Answer (score 0):

The issue was having used **apt** to install the packages as suggested by @mirek as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64175334/7158326). I removed the python3-virtualenv using `apt purge python3-virtualenv` and then install everything using pip
`/usr/bin/python3.8 -m pip install --force-reinstall virtualenvwrapper`

This seems to at least help me run the tests.